# How to reseume timer

Tags: android, timer

Hi I am making sport countdown timer and I have pause button. To pause timer I am using :(code bellow)
but I don't know hot to resume it. And I don't want to put my countdown timer function in public void method.

```
mButtonStartPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mTimerRunning) {
                pauseTimer();
            } else {
                startTimer();
            }
        }
    });
    mButtonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            resetTimer();
        }
    });
    mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            updateCountDownText();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mTimerRunning = false;
            mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");
            mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }.start();
    updateCountDownText();
}
private void startTimer() {

    mTimerRunning = true;
    mButtonStartPause.setText("pause");
    mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
private void pauseTimer() {
    mCountDownTimer.cancel();
    mTimerRunning = false;
    mButtonStartPause.setText("Start");
    mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
private void resetTimer() {
    mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
    updateCountDownText();
    mButtonReset.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    mButtonStartPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I checked your restart function. And I think solution to restart is to cancel it and start it again. Try this out:

```
private void resetTimer() {
mCountDownTimer.cancel();
mCountDownTimer.start();
}
```

Comment: I set value of time then I click start and I see on tex view time is counting down

Comment: Can you put your code here? Specifically code where you pause it

Comment: I am sorry but I would like to resume it not restart. My bad